# Firebase for Android send and receive images

Tags: android, image, chat, firebase

I am developing an Android application base on chat demo application done by Firebase. 
The problem I'm facing is when I want to transfer images, I don't know how to handle the situation.
for sending the image I encode it in Base64 and send it as a string. So how will be the process of decoding to the image again here?

Comment: Any links and codes?

Comment: If you encode base64 upon sending, you decode the base64 upon receiving it. Neither of those sides is specific to Firebase. As @Pedram already suggested, it will probably be a lot easier for us to help you if you include an MCVE in your question (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

you must try this.

```
byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(String,Base64.DEFAULT);

Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0,imageAsBytes.length);
```